# How to get SSI variable REQUEST_URI without query parameters

Tags: regex, ssi

I'm trying to get the pathname part of the REQUEST_URI, without the query parameters.  I need to do this in raw SSI, without any PHP or anything.

If I do something like `<!--#echo var="REQUEST_URI" -->`, that will output the pathname plus the query parameters, so if the browser URL shows http://example.com/foo.html?bar, that would return `/foo.html?bar`.  But I need to return only `/foo.html`.  Is there a way to do that directly inside an `echo` statement?

Note: It needs to use the requested uri only.  The actual file paths on the server are very different and I cannot display those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a running `nginx` with `SSI` around, so i am just guessing here.
But maybe you can try to use a regular expression to extract what you want.
Maybe something like this:

```
<!--# if expr="$REQUEST_URI = /(.+)\?.*/" -->
    <!--# echo var="1" -->
<!--# endif -->
```

I am not sure about the `\` before the `?`.

Comment: For future confused people, `/`'s need to be escaped, like as if your were declaring javascript regexes.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the `DOCUMENT_URI` variable instead:

```
<!--#echo var="DOCUMENT_URI" -->
```

`SCRIPT_NAME` seems to work too:

```
<!--#echo var="SCRIPT_NAME" -->
```

Comment: thanks, but `<!--#echo var="DOCUMENT_URI" -->` returns the server URI, not the URI that the user typed into their browser (we have some nginx rewrites which make those values different).  And `<!--#echo var="SCRIPT_NAME" -->` just returns `(none)`.

Comment: i see. weird that `SCRIPT_NAME` displays `(none)`. Did you try `PATH_INFO` (another CGI variable)?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me :

```
<!--#if expr="$REQUEST_URI = /([^?]+)\?.*/" -->
    <!--#set var="URL_WITHOUT_QUERY_STRING" value="$1" -->
    <!--#echo var='URL_WITHOUT_QUERY_STRING' -->
<!--#endif -->
```